# How to setup a Python project wit GPIOs on Intellij IDEA on Windows?

Tags: gpio, python

I'm struggling to this topic for a while.

**Enviroment**:

- Windows 10,
- Intellij IDEA Ultimate 2016.3.
- Python3 runs on the
  system.

If I try to `import RPi.GPIO from GPIO`i receive the message `No module named GPIO`. So, how can I include this package, or is there a known better concept? During the development process I wanna use some unit tests to keep a good quality of my code.

Comment: Import GPIO only works on the Pi as far as I am aware.

Answer (score 2):

What I often do (from Linux not Windows but the premise is the same), is set up a share (sshfs in my case, but Samba works equally well) that shares the repository/code working directory, and mount that into Windows. Then, in intelliJ, open that as your code base. In the terminal window within intelliJ, SSH (using Putty) to the Pi, and exec your code on the Pi directly. This allows you to code in your IDE, but work on and execute code on the Pi itself.

I often have a whole slew of tests for my code that can run on any platform, then a bunch that can only run on the Pi. To do this, you have to instruct the test to 'skip' if it's only to be run on the Pi, and for ones that don't require specific Pi functionality directly, you can use something like [mock](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html) to mock out the GPIO calls.

Although I don't use Python on my RPis, I do use techniques such as these in the Perl distributions I write. Here's an example that checks if a certain environment variable is set or not. If not, it skips all tests in the current unit test file:

```
if (! $ENV{PI_BOARD}){
    warn "\n*** PI_BOARD is not set! ***\n";
    plan skip_all => "not on a pi board\n";
}
```

Here's an example that does the same thing, but uses my [Mock::Sub](https://metacpan.org/pod/Mock::Sub) Perl distribution (it's equivalent to Python's 'Mock'). If the env var isn't set, it'll mock out certain functions/methods. If it is set, we're on a Pi board, so we can run natively with the original functions:

```
use Mock::Sub;
use RPi::WiringPi;
use Test::More;

my $mock = Mock::Sub->new;

my $pi;
my ($setup_sub);

if (! $ENV{PI_BOARD}){
    $setup_sub = $mock->mock(
        'RPi::WiringPi::setup_gpio',
        return => 1
    );
    $pi = RPi::WiringPi->new; # calls setup_gpio()
}
else {
    $pi = RPi::WiringPi->new;
}
```

Now, the above example is useful for cases where you need to perform tests that don't explicitly require a Pi board, but need an object. The constructor, `new()` calls `setup_gpio()` inherently. Obviously if you're not on a Pi board, it'll fail horribly. In this case, we mock out that functionality to trick the class that `setup_gpio()` ran correctly, and we get a full blown object, even if not on a RPi.

So mocking is handy for doing things where you can fake out certain calls (typically ones that are called from within other methods).

In both cases above, that allows me to have a nice test suite that covers many aspects of the software on non-Pi systems. If on a Pi, then the entire suite runs. Very useful when doing Continuous Integration on many systems, such as the [CPAN](http://cpan.org) Testers automated testing.

Doing things this way also allows you do to some of your coding on a normal workstation that doesn't require the Pi, while being able to run at least a portion of your test suite before you fetch the new code onto the Pi and run it completely there.

Answer (score 1):

RPi.GPIO only runs on a Raspberry Pi.

You will have to stub or simulate the calls.

I think it will be more sensible to run the unit tests on the Pi itself.  The time involved in stubbing or simulating the calls would probably be better spent on producing the unit tests.

Comment: Thank you for your fast reply, simulating packages likes https://github.com/Def4l71diot/RPi.GPIO-def ?

Comment: @michael-mammut What I often do (from Linux not Windows but the premise is the same), is set up a share (sshfs in my case, but Samba works equally well) that shares the repository/code working dir, and mount that into Windows. Then, in intelliJ, open that as your code base. In the terminal window, SSH (using Putty) to the Pi, and exec your code on the Pi directly. This allows you to code in your IDE, but work on and execute code on the Pi itself.

Comment: @michael-mammut Another thing... I often have a whole slew of tests for my code that can run on any platform, then a bunch that can only run on the Pi. To do this, you have to instruct the test to 'skip' if it's only to be run on the Pi, and for ones that don't require specific Pi functionality directly, you can use something like [mock](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html) to mock out the GPIO calls.

Comment: @stevieb I think your comments would make a good answer.

Comment: @joan Thanks. I'll whip something up in between the client meetings I'm on ;)